# Last few rows from a non-indexed table in Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, performance, ms-access, query-performance

I'm trying to run a query on an Oracle DB through SQL Server [dont' ask, it's a requirement]
The Oracle table in question [lets call it hugeTable] has over 200 million rows and no index. I'm not allowed to alter the structure in any way.
I need to fetch some rows from hugeTable for a inner join with another Oracle table from the same DB [not as large, can retrieve data easily].

The data in question [based on the criteria I have], is towards the end and as such takes forever to be pulled. This causes a timeout on the Oracle side of things and it returns no rows.
Running the query directly on Oracle DB returns the data but only if I set the timeout to 0.

My question is:
Is there a way to fetch the rows I need from hugeTable in this current scenario?

My query looks a bit like this:

```
SELECT 
TABLE1.COL1, TABLE1.COL2, TABLE2.COL1, ETC..
FROM TABLE1 
INNER JOIN TABLE2
ON [A COUPLE OF COLUMNS]
INNER JOIN hugeTable 
ON [A COUPLE OF COLUMNS]
GROUP BY 
a bunch of stuff
HAVING
hugeTable.Column1 = 'something'
and TABLE1.COLUMN3 = 'SOMETHING'
```

Comment: What does "last few rows" mean? There is no ordering in your query, which makes the question meaningless.

Comment: My apologies. I know I'm looking for the last few rows in the table because they are the most recent [based on date].

Comment: Not much you can do without an index. Are you allowed to put an AFTER INSERT trigger on the big table? You could use that to populate a smaller indexed table.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. No edits to the big table.

Comment: There's no "beginning" and "end" of a (normal) table, it's all just a big heap of stuff. If your filtering criteria aren't indexed, then the whole table needs to be traversed. Even if you know there's only one row and it was the last (or first) inserted, no shortcut if no index. No magic.

Comment: How much freedom do you have on the MS SQL end?  You could query the relevant records and cache them in a temp table on the MS SQL side, and join to that instead.

Comment: @Jon true, but that would become stale. He'd still have to tablescan many gigabytes.

Comment: There's no silver bullet here. The Oracle end will have to submit, plain and simple (the DBAs/business owners, whatever). You need to engage with them and talk some sense. We can't really solve business issues on this site

Comment: What about using `ROWID` pseudocolumn, like this: `select * from (select * from hugetable order by rowid) where rownum <= 2`. This query will give you last two inserted rows.

Comment: @cha ROWID doesn't tell you anything about when the row was inserted: https://community.oracle.com/thread/880161?tstart=0

Comment: This was very insightful guys. 

Based on all the answers here, I chose to make a business case to fix the data structure on the Oracle DB and for the meantime, cached a smaller subset of the data I need and broke the query down into multiple pieces.
Like Mat and Phil said, there is so shortcut/silver bullet.

Thank you all.